# django form - hide field label in form.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-1.7

I am using django 1.7 & python 2.7 and I have a custom form, where I want to hide the labels of specific form fields.

**Is it possible to hide the form field labels of specific form fields at the form.py level, rather than using jquery at the presentation level?**

I have tried some things, but I cannot seem to hide the form field label at the form.py level. The form field of the label I want to hide is **not** hidden.

I have searched SO & Google and the django docs, but I cannot find anything suitable.

I am not sure this can be done, but I thought I would ask, just in case it is possible to hide the form field labels at the form.py level - it would save me a lot of jquery code at the presentation level.

Here is the code I have:

```
class CaptchaPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):

    email = forms.EmailField()
    recaptcha = ReCaptchaField(public_key=settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY, private_key=settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY, attrs={'theme' : 'clean'})
    ....
```

I have tried the following, which do not work:

```
email = forms.EmailField(label='')

email = forms.EmailField(label=none)

email = forms.EmailField(label=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CaptchaPasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['recaptcha'].label = False
```

**EDIT**

Here is the full code of the form:

```
class CaptchaPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(label="")
    recaptcha = ReCaptchaField(public_key=settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY, private_key=settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY, attrs={'theme' : 'clean'}, label="")
```

Here is the output when the `label=""`:

```
Project-Id-Version: Django Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: POT-Creation-Date: 2014-05-19 15:12+0200 PO-Revision-Date: 2014-07-27 09:17+0000 Last-Translator: Palmux <Palmux@Gmail.Com> Language-Team: Italian (Http://Www.Transifex.Com/Projects/P/Django/Language/It/) MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: Text/Plain; Charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Language: It Plural-Forms: Nplurals=2; Plural=(N != 1); :
```

Comment: Both `label=False` and `label=''` should do the trick - there will be no label. What does not suit you?

Comment: chem1st, using `label=False` renders **False** as the actual label and `label=''` renders a lot of python code as the label.

Comment: It's weird, cause `label=''` really **should** work. Show more code in your forms.py and template. Is it a ModelForm?

Comment: chem1st - I have added the form code and the output as an edit in the OP.

Comment: The problem still present if you set an empty label only for email field, but not for recaptcha?

Comment: the problem persists for both fields.